# ASP.Net form throwing SQL exception

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When trying to save and store data in a local SQL database, a SQL exception is thrown,

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)"

Initially I thought that something was wrong with the way I had made a new data connection. After making new table 3 times, the problem persisted. Then I tried to re-install the SQL modules of Visual Studio, they also did not yield a +ve result.

No data can be read from/stored to the table. Please Help.

```
public partial class signup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=KidzQuiz;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;


protected void signupClick(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (checkDuplicate() != 0)
        //signup_error.Text = "User already exists";
    //else if (checkEmpty() != 1)
       // signup_error.Text = "One or more fields is missing";
    //else
    //{
        string sqlcmd = "insert into User (name, email, school, city, standard, section) values (@n, @em, @sc, @city, @st, @sec)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", email_signup.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sc", school.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", standard.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", section.SelectedItem.ToString());
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    //}
}
```

}

Comment: I guess the connection string is wrong - `(localdb)\v11.0` looks very strange to me. Can you connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio? If so: What are the server and instance name? I also suggest you use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead of manually creating a connection string.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "they also did not yield a +ve result"?

Comment: Your connection string doesn't seem ordinary, why don't you take a look at [Connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)?

Answer (score 0):

In LocalDB local databases you have to give the path to the Database file also.

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

|DataDirectory| represents App_Data folder of the application